# Meaning of "Let's move it!"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> "I'm making Chicken Pilaf tonight," the baker's wife chimes in. "I hope you like it."
>
> "Wonderful, wonderful," the Count says, with a smile, as he pushes her aside into some laundry. Then, opening a closet door by mistake, he walks in. "Christ, where's the goddamn front door?"
>
> "Ach," laughs the baker's wife, "such a funny man, the Count."
>
> "I knew you'd like that," Dracula says, forcing a chuckle, "now get out of my way." At last he opens the front door but time has run out on him.
>
> "Oh, look, mama," says the baker, "the eclipse must be over. The sun is coming out again."
>
> "Right," says Dracula, slamming the front door. "I've decided to stay. Pull down the window shades quickly— quickly! **Let's move it!**"
>
> "What window shades?" asks the baker.

It is not clear to me that "it" refer to sun or curtains?

But I think "it" refer to Sun and this phrase mean: to not allow the rays of Sun to come home
Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, "it" doesn't refer to anything specifically; rather, the phrase "let's move it!" is an idiom meaning to hurry up. Dracula isn't telling them to move any particular item; he just wants them to be quick!

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/move-it